# Proof that $ax=0$ has not only the trivial solution in order the system be linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

I have some vectors and i want to show that they are linearly dependent. I know that they're deterninant is zero. Is this the solution? I must do it with $Ax=0$, because i should use homogeneus system, how can i tell that this  equation has not only the trivial solution?

Comment: Just find a non-zero solution. Usually solving systems of linear equations is taught before determinants.

Answer (score 0):

we get non-trivial solution from Ax=0 if number of unknowns is greater in number than equations in this system.